# Error for defining class method as expression

Tags: racket

I am trying to define a class method like so:

```
#lang racket
(define foo% (class object%
  (super-new)
  (define/public plus-one (curry + 1))))
```

But this code produces the following error:
`eval:2:0: class: bad form for method definition`

According to the Racket documentation, it should be possible to define a method using the syntax `(define/public id expr)`, so I don't understand why this isn't working.

There is an easy workaround by using the `(define/public (id . formals) body ...+)` syntax, of course, but I would like to understand why the current code isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation for `class*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._class%2A%29%29), see the nonterminals named *method-definition* and *method-procedure*. They describe the constraints on a legal method definition. A paragraph later in the `class` docs says that each `private`, `public`, etc declaration must correspond to a *method-definition*. So it isn't a bug, it's the intended behavior.

The reason behind the behavior, by the way, is that Racket's `class` macro implements methods by rewriting the method's `lambda` (or `case-lambda`) expression(s) to add an implicit argument for `this`. The same argument is also implicitly used to access the object's public and private fields. Restricting method definitions to certain shapes makes it possible to find the right `lambda` expressions to adjust.

Here's one way of rewriting your example:

```
#lang racket
(define do-plus-one (curry + 1))
(define foo% (class object%
  (super-new)
  (define/public (plus-one n) (do-plus-one n)))
```

This has the following nice properties: `do-plus-one` is computed only once, and it doesn't take a field slot in each `foo%` object.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug. Imagine we have the usuall way:

```
(define/public (plus-one n) (+ 1 n))
```

The `define` way with name and arguments in parentheses are sugar for a `id` and `lambda` and that works:

```
(define/public plus-one (lambda (n) (+ 1 n)))
```

I'm getting that `(curry + 1)` returns a similar lambda and that that object should be working, but it isn't.

The whole point with a class method is using the private fields from the object and none of them do that, however only `curry` version makes it obvious that it will not be able to since the resulting procedure won't be having the scope of the object.

If you imagined we used a private variable for the increment you couldn't use `curry` since it would cache it. eg. you can't replicate this:

```
(define increaser%
  (class object%
    (init inc)
    (define increment inc)
    (super-new)
    (define/public (set-inc inc)
      (set! increment inc))
    (define/public (increase n)
      (+ increment n))))

(define test (new increaser% [inc 2]))
(send test increase 1) ; ==> 3
(send test set-inc 3)
(send test increase 1) ; ==> 4
(define test2 (new increaser% [inc 21]))
(define value 13)
(map (lambda (obj) (send obj increase value)) (list test test2))
; ==> (16 34)
```